# Check if program still connected with localhost (in JDBC)?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I created a connection to `localhost` using JDBC. It's fine there, But what if I want to know if connection is still there? My code:

```
class Connection_maker
{
  private Connection conn;
  private static final String DESTINATION = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/";
  public Connection_maker()
  {
     try
     {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        this. conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DESTINATION, "root", "");
        System.out.println("connected");
     } 
     catch (Exception e)
     {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       new Connection_maker();
   }
}
```

I tried to use `java.util.Timer` to schedule a TimerTask every 1 minute, but I have to create another connection and I think it's not efficient way. I tried  `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException` in catch block, but it's not working.

Is there a way to know if the connection is still there?

Comment: Look at [`Connection.isValid(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#isValid-int-) or consider using a connection pool library that does that type of checks for you.

Comment: finally! It works! :) thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use the connection to execute the query "select 1". This is very lightweight.

```
bool isAlive(){
   try{
      String query = "SELECT 1";
      Statement st = this.conn.createStatement(ue);
      ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
      return true;
   }catch(SQLException e){
      // honestly kind of non-specific ??
      return false;
   }
}
```